# VSCode debugger auto attach to subprocess

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pydev, bottle

In the console output below, it clearly say breakpoints won't work in new process.  Where is this **debugger settings** for attaching to sub-process?

```
pydev debugger: starting

pydev debugger: New process is launching (breakpoints won't work in the new process).
pydev debugger: To debug that process please enable 'Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging?' option in the debugger settings.

Bottle v0.12.13 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As of late 2018, VSCode can debug a python subprocess.   We just need to set the configuration correctly.   In Visual Studio Code, edit the `launch.json` file and add a `"subProcess": true` key value pair to the debugging configuration you are using.  Here is an example.

```
"configurations": [
   {
       "name": "Python: Current File",
       "type": "python",
       "request": "launch",
       "subProcess": true,
       "program": "${file}",
       "console": "integratedTerminal"
   }
```

]

Comment: I have  `"subProcess": false`. But I am still able to debug into the supProcess module. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to attach to sub-process.
However, I was facing the same problem while debugging my python flask, and I noticed that the `pydev debugger: New process is launching ...` problem correlated to my use of `use_reloader=True` in my app.run. When I removed that, the breakpoints worked fine!

Comment: I do see a toggle-able `Auto Attach: Off` option on the status bar at bottom.